# Concat overlapping videos with ffmpeg using python3

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a number of videos that overlap in time that were downloaded from an online video stream:

`0m00s  - 15m10s
14m50s - 30m20s
...`

The first few seconds (usually around 20 seconds) of a video segment duplicate last few seconds of the previous segment.

I'd like to concat the video segments and form a single video file without duplicate parts. I can do it programmatically using `ffmpeg` libraries to find the cut points by minimizing error between a frame of the current segment and the last frame of the previous segment.

Is there a way to achieve this with an ffmpeg command?

Comment: If the files have absolute timestamps, it may be possible. But if no, it's not possible in a single command. You can run one command to find join point betweeen two consecutive segments using blend filter/blackframe and then write a concat demuxer text file with the required inpoint/outpoint

Comment: I just checked with `-vf showinfo`, and it seems they do not have absolute timestamps, but they do have some checksums (are these useful for finding exact duplicates?)

Thanks for the pointer on blend/blackframe - googling it.

Comment: You need to add `-copyts` else ffmpeg will remove any starting offset before it gets to the filter.

Comment: It seems `framemd5` matching is enough for my videos. I can make `framemd5` files for every video segment and fetch out dts / pts of the starting frame in every segment. Is there a way to concat with dts / pts inpoints instead of timestamps?

Comment: No, time has to be in seconds.

Comment: I found that `trim` filter has `start_pts` option, but I can't make it work with `pts` values extracted from `framemd5` output (`start` with seconds works, but `start_pts` does not)

Comment: If someone lands here needing a "fuzzier" match than `framemd5`, see https://superuser.com/questions/663731/find-video-file-position-using-an-image-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following script to solve my problem. It uses `framemd5` checksums to find the inpoints in time and then uses the `concat` demuxer (thanks @Gyan for the tip!).

```py
# Usage: ffmpeg $(python3 script.py input1.mp4 input2.mp4) -y -an output.mp4

import os
import sys
import subprocess

ffmpeg_concat_echo, md5_last_frame = '', None

for video_path in map(os.path.abspath, sys.argv[1:]):
        framemd5 = subprocess.check_output(['ffmpeg', '-nostats', '-hide_banner', '-i', video_path, '-an', '-f', 'framemd5', '-c', 'copy', '-'], stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        tb_num, tb_den = 1, 1
        inpoint = 0.0
        for line in framemd5.split(b'\n'):
                if line.startswith(b'#tb'):
                        tb_num, tb_den = list(map(int, line.split()[-1].split(b'/')))
                elif line and not line.startswith(b'#'):
                        splitted = line.split(b',')
                        md5 = splitted[-1].strip()
                        pts_time = float(splitted[2]) * tb_num / tb_den
                        if md5_last_frame is not None and md5 == md5_last_frame:
                                inpoint = pts_time
        md5_last_frame = md5
        ffmpeg_concat_echo += 'echo "file {}"; echo "inpoint {}";'.format(video_path, inpoint);

print('-nostats -hide_banner -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts -f concat -safe 0 -i <({}) -c copy'.format(ffmpeg_concat_echo))
```

Below is another version ([source](https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18), [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230311234256/https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18)) which supports exact PTS inpoints using `concat` video filter; computing inpoints using explicit frame differences.

```py
# Usage: ffmpeg $(( echo input1.mp4; echo input2.mp4 ) | python3 concat_overlapping_video_framemd5_demuxer.py concat_file.txt) -y -an output.mp4

import os
import sys
import subprocess

ffmpeg_concat_file, md5_last_frame = open(sys.argv[1], 'w'), None
for video_path in map(os.path.abspath, list(map(str.strip, sys.stdin))):
        framemd5 = subprocess.check_output(['ffmpeg', '-nostats', '-hide_banner', '-i', video_path, '-an', '-f', 'framemd5', '-c', 'copy', '-'], stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        inpoint, tb_num, tb_den = 0, 1, 1
        for line in framemd5.split(b'\n'):
                if line.startswith(b'#tb'):
                        tb_num, tb_den = list(map(int, line.split()[-1].split(b'/')))
                elif not line.startswith(b'#') and len(line) > 0:
                        splitted = line.split(b',')
                        md5, pts_time = splitted[-1].strip(), float(splitted[2]) * tb_num / tb_den
                        if md5 == md5_last_frame:
                                inpoint = pts_time
        md5_last_frame = md5
        ffmpeg_concat_file.write('file {}\ninpoint {}\n'.format(video_path, inpoint))

print('-nostats -hide_banner -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts -f concat -safe 0 -i {} -c copy'.format(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: This may result in "Non-monotonous DTS" errors. Some ways to solve:
1) Use `concat` video filter. Downsides: will re-encode
2) [Extract streams and re-assemble them back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691943/ffmpeg-concat-poduces-dts-out-of-order-errors). Downsides: will make a file copy, unless [named pipes are used](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#Usingnamedpipestoavoidintermediatefiles)
3) Wait until [this patch](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2018-March/226706.html) gets merged. Hopefully it would fix the problem

Comment: is there better version of it, gist isn't working

Comment: This worked great for stitching some security camera footage together, thank you.

Comment: The gist link is broken, could you please share the code again in a more permanent way?

Comment: [Revised gist](https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230311234256/https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18)), [original gist](https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18/321290839cde9a33efa22ad458e5e653de1e5a97) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230311234353/https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18/321290839cde9a33efa22ad458e5e653de1e5a97)), [revisions](https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18/revisions).

Comment: Continued from [above](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/concat-overlapping-videos-with-ffmpeg-using-python3#comment46618_24689): [archived revisions](https://web.archive.org/web/20230311234407/https://gist.github.com/yar/5056e5bd303a23de98139365d2ff5d18/revisions).